# mousePressEvent is not getting in my Parent Widget

Tags: qt

I have two customized widgets of which one acts as a parent and another as child.

Parent inherits QScrollArea, and child inherits QWidget.

I am not getting mousepressevent in my parent widget when i click the child widget.

```
// child widget 
//table.h


    #ifndef TABLE_H
    #define TABLE_H

    #include <QWidget>
    #include <QGridLayout>
    #include <QLabel>
    #include <QPoint>
    #include <QMouseEvent>

    class Table : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        public:
        explicit Table(QWidget *parent = 0);

        private:
        QString m_id,
                m_type,
                m_image,
                m_sectionId;
        QPoint  m_position;
        int     m_seatCount;

        QGridLayout *m_pMainLayout;
        QLabel      *m_pTableImage,
                    *m_pBottomLabel,
                    *m_pSeatImage;

        public:
        ...

        //protected:
        //    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
        //    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
        //    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
        //    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

        signals:

        public slots:

    };

    #endif // TABLE_H

// table.cpp
    #include "table.h"
    #include <QDebug>
    #include <QApplication>

    Table::Table(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        m_seatCount(0)
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";

        m_pMainLayout   = new QGridLayout(this);
        m_pTableImage   = new QLabel(this);
        m_pBottomLabel  = new QLabel(this);
        m_pSeatImage    = new QLabel(this);

        if (NULL != m_pMainLayout && NULL != m_pTableImage &&
            NULL != m_pBottomLabel  && NULL != m_pSeatImage)
        {
            setLayout(m_pMainLayout);
            m_pMainLayout->addWidget(m_pTableImage, 0, 0, 2, 2);
            m_pMainLayout->addWidget(m_pBottomLabel, 2, 0);
            m_pMainLayout->addWidget(m_pSeatImage, 2, 1);

            m_pTableImage->setObjectName("tableImage");
            m_pBottomLabel->setObjectName("bottomLabel");
            m_pSeatImage->setObjectName("seatImage");
        }

        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
    }


//Parent widget
//hearderfile

    #ifndef TABLESOURCESCROLLAREA_H
    #define TABLESOURCESCROLLAREA_H

    #include <QScrollArea>
    #include <QVBoxLayout>
    #include <QMouseEvent>
    #include <QDataStream>
    #include <QMimeData>
    #include <QPoint>
    #include <QDrag>

    #include "tablesourcewidget.h"
    #include "table.h"

    class TableSourceScrollArea : public QScrollArea
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        public:
        explicit TableSourceScrollArea(QWidget *parent = 0);

        private:

        void createDislpay();

        //TableSourceWidget   *m_pTableSourceWidget;
        QVBoxLayout         *m_pMainVLayout;


        Table   *m_pSquareTable,
        *m_pCircleTable,
        *m_pOvalTable,
        *m_pRectangleTable;

        protected:
        void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);


        signals:

        public slots:

    };

    #endif // TABLESOURCESCROLLAREA_H

// source file

    #include "tablesourcescrollarea.h"
    #include <QDebug>

    TableSourceScrollArea::TableSourceScrollArea(QWidget *parent) :
        QScrollArea(parent)
    {
        createDislpay();
    }

    void TableSourceScrollArea::createDislpay()
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";

        m_pMainVLayout      = new QVBoxLayout(this);

        m_pSquareTable      = new Table(this);
        m_pCircleTable      = new Table(this);
        m_pOvalTable        = new Table(this);
        m_pRectangleTable   = new Table(this);

        if (NULL != m_pSquareTable  && NULL != m_pCircleTable &&
            NULL != m_pOvalTable    && NULL != m_pRectangleTable &&
            NULL != m_pMainVLayout)
        {
            setLayout(m_pMainVLayout);
            // source tables
            m_pMainVLayout->addWidget(m_pSquareTable);
            m_pMainVLayout->addWidget(m_pCircleTable);
            m_pMainVLayout->addWidget(m_pOvalTable);
            m_pMainVLayout->addWidget(m_pRectangleTable);
        ...
        }

        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
    }

    void TableSourceScrollArea::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";

        Table *table = static_cast<Table*>(childAt(event->pos()));
        if (!table)
        {
            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exit NULL Param";
            return;
        }

        ...
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
    }
```

as read from article : [mouse event propagation](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2006/05/27/mouse-event-propagation/)

I get to know if child widget doesn't implement event handlers it will be pass to parent widget. But my parent widget handler is not getting is not getting invoked when i click on child. 
Can someone tell where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you test if the child gets the event if you add an event handler to it?

Comment: @Silicomancer: yes.. i check it already. It gets the event. But as per the document given, if i implement handler in child it will accept the event by default and no event is sent to parent. I even tried calling QApplication::sendEvent(parentWidget(), (QEvent*)event); in child handler, that too doesnt invoke parent's handler :(

Comment: I suppose there is something about scroll areas that we do not know. Did you try to make the tables child of something more basic? Lets say child of a plain QWidget derivative. Does that kind of parent get the event?

Comment: Call `event->ignore();`.

Comment: Thanks. For time being I’ve changed my parent widget inheriting from QWidget and it works :) I got these info :
The Scroll ares itself does not accept the events, rather the scroll area’s viewport accepts those events. Rather than subclassing the scroll area to create the event handler, install the event handler on the scroll area’s viewport().
Here is a decent article on this issue
http://www.setnode.com/blog/mouse-wheel-events-event-filters-and-qscrollarea/